# Using Joda-Time to get UTC offset for a given date and timezone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, utc

I have dates in the format 20Jan2013, 08Aug2012 etc, with their own specific timezones. So for example, 20Jan2013 might have a timezone ID of Australia/Melbourne, and 08Aug2012 might have an ID of Europe/London. What I want to do is, based on these timezones and the dates, calculate the UTC offset for that timezone on the given date. I've come up with this so far:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ");
DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMMYYYY");

DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Melbourne");  

DateTime thisDate = dtf1.parseDateTime("30Jul2013");                                            
System.out.println("\nZone: " + thisDate.withZone(zone));
```

This gives me the output:

```
Zone: 2013-07-30T00:00:00.000+10:00
```

This is correct, but I would like to extract just the UTC offset from this, which in this case is +10:00. I've looked for ways to do this but can't find anything. Is there any way I can do this? The only option I see is to convert the output to a String and use the substring method to get the UTC offset.

The above code does take DST (Daylight Saving Time) into account. So for example if I had: 
DateTime thisDate = dtf1.parseDateTime("30Jan2013");

The output would be: 2013-01-30T00:00:00.000+11:00

(+11:00 at the end instead of +10:00)

So basically all I need to do is find a way to extract +11:00 from 2013-07-30T00:00:00.000+11:00. Please help!

Comment: You need a time-of-day as well as a date to determine the offset-from-UTC. For example, on the DST cutover day in the United States when the offset jumps an hour at 2 AM, 1 AM has a different offset than 4 AM. One date, two offsets.

Answer (score 16):

### Simple Method for Obtaining Timezone Name and Offset in Hours

```
public static String getCurrentTimeZoneOffset() {
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    Long instant = DateTime.now().getMillis();

    String name = tz.getName(instant);

    long offsetInMilliseconds = tz.getOffset(instant);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours( offsetInMilliseconds );
    String offset = Long.toString( hours );

    return name + " (" + offset + " Hours)";
    // Example: "Mountain Standard Time (-7 Hours)"
}
```

#### Couple caveats:

- This gets the default `DateTimeZone` from **JodaTime**. You can modify it to accept a specific DateTimeZone that is passed into the method.
- This returns it in a format like "**Mountain Standard Time (-7 Hours)**" but you can format it as you see fit quite easily.

Hope that helps.

JP

Comment: caveat: offset might include half an hour, such as in India. So "long hours" will miss it.

Comment: Rather than using `TimeUnit` (which drops fractional values, as @auval notes), just use [`tz.getName(instant)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getName-long-).

Answer (score 4):

In order for Joda to give the correct offset, you must provide a datetime instant.Without a datetime instant, it is impossible to calculate the offset since we have different offsets(daylight savings). This is how I would use Joda to get offset in  + HH:mm format :

```
    int offsetInMillis = DateTimeZone.forID(zoneId).getOffset(new DateTime().getMillis());
    String offset = String.format("%02d:%02d", Math.abs(offsetInMillis / 3600000),
            Math.abs((offsetInMillis / 60000) % 60));
    offset = (offsetInMillis >= 0 ? "+" : "-") + offset;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the timezone offset, use `DateTimeZone.forID()` to get the time zone and then `tz.getOffset(instant)` to get the offset to UTC in milliseconds.

It may look odd that you need an instant to calculate the offset to UTC but this is necessary to take Daylight Savings into account as well as changes in the timezone. Yes, countries change their timezones once in a while:

> [Why does timezone data change?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html#change)
>
> Timezone settings are adopted locally, and there is no world timezone authority.

**EDIT** This gives you the correct result:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddMMMYYYY");

    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Melbourne");  

    DateTime thisDate = dtf1.parseDateTime("30Jul2013").withZone(zone);                                            
    assertEquals( 10 * CommonConstants.MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR,
        zone.getOffset( thisDate ) );
```

thisDate.get

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the above code does take DST (Daylight Saving Time) into account. So for example if I had:
DateTime thisDate = dtf1.parseDateTime("30Feb2013");

The output would be:
2013-07-30T00:00:00.000+11:00


(+11:00 at the end instead of +10:00)

Comment: Sorry about how does the below code work?

assertEquals( 10 * CommonConstants.MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR,
        zone.getOffset( thisDate ) );

It gives me an error for CommonConstants. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: It's a class that I wrote which contains constants that I use all the time. The main purpose is to make the code readable. Don't you agree that it's easy for you to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 [introduced better Date and Time handling](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) to address some of the language's previous limitations in that area. A few of my projects have started to use it rather than Joda.

Using the java.time package:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.of(2013 , 1 , 20).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne"));
    ZoneOffset zo = dateTime.getOffset();
    int offset = zo.getTotalSeconds();

    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(offset);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(offset % 3600);
```

The hours variable is set to 11 and the minutes to 0.

It also calculates the minutes-offset, for time zones that are partial hours, such as Newfoundland and Labrador in eastern Canada:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.of(2013, 1, 20).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of("Canada/Newfoundland"));
```

In this case, the offset is `-03:30` (three and a half hours behind UTC), `hours` is -3 and `minutes` is -30.

For the String representation, rather than the integer number of hours and minutes, use the ZoneOffset's toString() method. So for the example above, use:

```
String offsetString = zo.toString();
```

Comment: Good answer, but could be better. You assume a day always starts at 00:00:00 but that is not the case in some time zones. Better to let java.time determine first moment of day: `LocalDate.of( 2013 , 1 , 20 ).atStartOfDay( myZoneId )`. Also, the Question asked for a string of the entire offset rather than numbers. The `ZoneOffset::toString` method gives you that string. So entire solution can be one line: `LocalDate.of( 2013 , 1 , 20 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne") ).getOffset().toString()`

Comment: @BasilBourque fair points. I used 00:00:00 since it appeared in the OP's text although not in their code. As I read the Question, they want the offset and knew they could extract it from the String if necessary, but wanted a better way. I will edit the response to improve it with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When you know offset and timestamp so in order to get current time you can use

```
 public static String formatMonthDayMinuteByGivenUtcOffset(long timestamp, int offset) {
        return JODA_FORMATTER.print(createDateTime(timestamp, offset));
    }
```