# org.joda.time | Day Light Saving time (DST) and local time zone offset

Tags: java, time, timezone, jodatime, dst

just to verify this: I have this lame and brain dead method to calculate the time zone offset for my current location. I wonder if I need to adjust it when Day Light Saving time comes into question (currently we have Winter Time at my location, CET time zone, so it's hard to verify).

```
// The local time zone's offset
private  int getLocalOffset() {
    DateTimeZone defaultZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    return defaultZone.getOffset(null) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
}
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: You shouldn't use an int in hours to represent the local zone offset. Many places actually have a half hour offset (for example: India). You couldn't represent that with your int. There is a reason joda time represents it with a number of milliseconds.

Comment: That's a good idea. I almost forgot about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, Joda time will take care of DST by itself, so you don't have to worry about it. However, I notice that you are passing `null` to getOffset(). Given that the time zone offset depends on the date, you really should be passing the date/time at which you are calculating the offset, or you're going to get wrong results.

Also as mentionned in my previous comment: Be aware that some timezones have an offset that isn't a whole number of hours. India for example is at GMT +5:30

Answer (score 8):

Time zones and Daylight Saving Time are a nightmare. You certainly shouldn't take on this task yourself. Let Joda-Time do the heavy lifting.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602729/642706) to similar question, [Using Joda time to get UTC offset for a given date and timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14602610/642706). The class [DateTimeZone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) offers a [getOffset()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29) method.

Example source code in Joda-Time 2.3 in Java 7…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

org.joda.time.DateTimeZone californiaTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");

org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime(californiaTimeZone);
int millisecondOffsetToAddToUtcToGetLocalTime = californiaTimeZone.getOffset( now );

System.out.println( "millisecondOffsetToAddToUtcToGetLocalTime: " + millisecondOffsetToAddToUtcToGetLocalTime );

// Note the casting to doubles to avoid integer truncation. Time zone offsets are NOT always whole hours.
System.out.println( "Offset in decimal hours: " + (double)millisecondOffsetToAddToUtcToGetLocalTime / 1000d / 60d / 60d );
```

When run at 2013-11-20T01:03:56.464-08:00…

```
millisecondOffsetToAddToUtcToGetLocalTime: -28800000
millisecondOffsetToAddToUtcToGetLocalTime in hours: -8.0
```

**IMPORTANT** That number format **`-8.0` is incorrect** for an offset. Must be either:

- `-08:00` with the colon and double digits (padded with leading zero).
- `-08` with leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine. To verify that it is correct - instead of passing null pass in a `DateTime` object to `DateTimeZone.getOffset` - set the datetime to sometime in summer when you know DST is in effect - you should see the offset value change.