# How to calculate remaining time between dates with daylight saving end date

Tags: java, android

I have following dates:

Start: 2017-09-11T00:00:00+01:00
End: 2017-11-13T00:00:00+01:00

Subtracting the milliseconds of the end data with start data is not the correct result for my timezone (Europe/Brussels) because of the daylight savings. On the 29th of October the clock will get set back 1 hour at night.

How should we handle this in Java/Android?

I've tried using Joda Time but to no avail. It's one hour off.

Comment: Have you read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java)?

Answer (score 3):

In `Java8`, you would use `ZonedDateTime`. Here is the [official api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

And a working example for your case:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;

// Start: 2017-09-11T00:00:00+02:00
LocalDateTime localDateTimeStart = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.SEPTEMBER, 11, 0, 0, 0);
// End: 2017-11-13T00:00:00+01:00 (instead of +02:00)
LocalDateTime localDateTimeEnd = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 13, 0, 0, 0);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeStart = localDateTimeStart.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels"));
System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeStart: " + formatter.format(zonedDateTimeStart));

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeEnd = localDateTimeEnd.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels"));
System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeEnd: " + formatter.format(zonedDateTimeEnd));

System.out.println("Remaining time in hours: " + ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(zonedDateTimeStart, zonedDateTimeEnd));
```

which produces:

```
ZonedDateTimeStart: 2017-09-11T00:00:00+02:00[Europe/Brussels]
ZonedDateTimeEnd: 2017-11-13T00:00:00+01:00[Europe/Brussels]
Remaining time in hours: 1513
```

**UPDATE:**

For a pre-`java8` solution, based on `Joda time`, use this:

```
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone yourTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Brussels");
org.joda.time.DateTime start = new org.joda.time.DateTime(2017, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0, yourTimeZone);
org.joda.time.DateTime end = new org.joda.time.DateTime(2017, 11, 13, 0, 0, 0, yourTimeZone);
org.joda.time.Duration durationInHours = new org.joda.time.Duration(start, end);
System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeStart: " + start);
System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeEnd: " + end);
System.out.println("Remaining time in hours: " + durationInHours.toStandardHours().getHours());
```

which produces:

```
ZonedDateTimeStart: 2017-09-11T00:00:00.000+02:00
ZonedDateTimeEnd: 2017-11-13T00:00:00.000+01:00
Remaining time in hours: 1513
```

Comment: Thank you, but any suggestion how to handle it for older Java versions?

Comment: **@Sander Versluys** For that, you can check this answer of **@Basil Bourque** here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20091301/2736843.